# How to sum values from two columns in R based on conditions from two other columns?

Tags: r, sum, multiple-conditions

[image]

[image]

```
       HomeTeam    AwayTeam FTHG FTAG FTR HST AST
1   Aston Villa       Wigan    0    2   A   5   7
26    Liverpool Aston Villa    1    3   A  12   4
34  Aston Villa      Fulham    2    0   H   4   3
45   Birmingham Aston Villa    0    1   A   7   5
48  Aston Villa  Portsmouth    2    0   H   5  12
58    Blackburn Aston Villa    2    1   H   7   5
76  Aston Villa    Man City    1    1   D   6   7
```

I have a dataframe 'mydata' part of which is shown above. It shows the results of soccer games in England.

I want to sum the goals scored by a team such as Aston Villa, possibly by looping through the dataframe. This would require counting Villa's FTHG when they are the HomeTeam, and Villa's FTAG when they are the away team.

I tried

```
with(mydata, sum(FTHG[HomeTeam == "Aston Villa"] | FTAG[AwayTeam == "Aston Villa"]))
```

and

```
sum(subset(mydata,(HomeTeam == "Aston Villa")$FTHG|(AwayTeam == "Aston Villa")$FTAG))
```

and

```
sum(subset(mydata,(HomeTeam == "Aston Villa")$FTHG|subset(mydata,(AwayTeam == "Aston Villa")$FTAG)))
```

none of which worked.

What I want is the total to be shown. Can this be done without summing the home and away data separately then adding?

Comment: Please don't add images of data/code, they are not helpful. Add data using `dput`.  Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can do

```
sum(unlist(Map(function(x, y) x[y],  mydata[c("FTHG", "FTAG")], 
  list(mydata$HomeTeam=="Aston Villa", mydata$AwayTeam=="Aston Villa"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sum(mydata[mydata$HomeTeam=="AstonVilla", "FTHG"], mydata[mydata$AwayTeam=="AstonVilla", "FTAG"])
```

You get the sum for all items in dataframe `mydata` that have column `HomeTeam` **or** AwayTeam for the given team (in this case AstonVilla).

Answer (score 0):

One base R option is via `which`

```
> sum(mydata[c("FTHG","FTAG")][which(mydata == "Aston Villa",arr.ind = TRUE)])
[1] 10
```

**Data**

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(HomeTeam = c("Aston Villa", "Liverpool", "Aston Villa", 
"Birmingham", "Aston Villa", "Blackburn", "Aston Villa"), AwayTeam = c("Wigan",
"Aston Villa", "Fulham", "Aston Villa", "Portsmouth", "Aston Villa",
"Man City"), FTHG = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 1L), FTAG = c(2L, 
3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), FTR = c("A", "A", "H", "A", "H", "H",
"D"), HST = c(5L, 12L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 6L), AST = c(7L, 4L, 3L,
5L, 12L, 5L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "26",
"34", "45", "48", "58", "76"))
```